# SSRS Tablix Conditional formatting by row number

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, conditional-statements, row-number

how can i use conditional formatting a particular row in the tablix object. Example table is 2 columns wide and has 7 rows showing salaries and names for 6 people. How can i format the 6th row?

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned what you would like to format in the 6th row,
but to apply different settings/expression on certain row numbers in a table you could use the `RowNumber` function. For example, for the background color on your table row, you can apply something like the following expresssion:

```
=IIF(RowNumber("YOUR_GROUPING") = 6, "White", "PaleGreen")
```

This should set, the color only on the 6th row to white.

More information visit:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255249.aspx